# Is there a way to check all of the power automate flow runs on a power apps canvas application? I'm having troubles building this solution

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

Clicking on "all runs" only gives you a 28-day run history.
[image: Example 'all runs']
I was able to extract all runs using power apps powerShell but I still can't figure a way out to send this data to a power apps cancas application.

I tried a powershell script and it works but I need the results on a power apps canvas app

Comment: So you were able to get flow run history past the last 28 days using PowerShell? According to this, the limit is 28 days: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/missing-runs-or-triggers-history-for-a-flow